# .gitignore not working even when I clear the cache

Tags: git

I made the mistake of creating a gitignore file after I had already pushed an initial commit to my git repo.

My .gitignore is very simple, it only contains:

```
node_modules
```

I've tried the following:

```
git rm --cached -rf .
git add .
git commit 'Fix untracked files'
git push
```

I've also tried deleting my `.git` folder in my project directory and reinitializing the entire project.

Both times it still pushes my `node_modules` directory!

How do I fix this?

Comment: Put a slash at the end of the folder name

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr doesn't work still

Comment: Have you already committed and pushed `node_modules` folder in the initial commit?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It should ignore your folder unless the repo has tracked it already. Your question and the current status of your repo are unclear. Also it has nothing to do with pushing AFAIK, and I am not sure what cache you are referring to. Do you mean stage?

Comment: @SajibKhan yes I have. But I tried deleting the github repo and the .git folder and reinitializing it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I want the gitignore file to actually ignore `node_modules` and not push it to my github repository. The repo is tracking it, but I tried to untrack it by running the command `git rm -rf --cached .` which didnt work for me

Comment: Now, what is your final/current state, node_modules exists in remote or not, also you have any commit in local?

Comment: @SajibKhan Unsure what you meant by your question - sorry a bit of a newbie here. But node_modules is currently present on my github repo: https://github.com/drhectapus/Voting-App

Comment: What git status shows after you ran that?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr After running `git rm -rf --cached .` and then `git status` it shows that it's deleted all files and folders in my project directory and every file and folder is now untracked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. First, remove the `node_modules` from .gitignore file (so, .gitignore is empty now).
2. Clean the git cache and Delete the node_modules folder.

   ```
   $ git rm -r --cached node_modules    # clean git cache
   $ rm -rf node_modules                # delete node_modules
   ```
3. Do git Add, Commit, Push to remote. Now, node_modules will be removed from remote.

   ```
   $ git add -A
   $ git commit -m 'Delete node_modules'
   $ git push origin HEAD
   ```
4. Add `node_modules` in .gitignore file, clear git cache, generate node_modules folder.

   ```
   # add 'node_modules/' into .gitignore

   $ git rm -r --cached node_modules
   $ npm i          # generate node_modules

   $ git status     # see if git ignores node_modules folder now
   ```
5. Do git Add, Commit, Push to remote. Now .gitignore contains node_modules so git will ignore the folder in future.

   ```
   $ git add .
   $ git commit -m 'Add node_modules in .gitignore'
   $ git push origin HEAD
   ```

Comment: Worked a charm. Thank you